# Can I run a list of datasets through a function using for()?

Tags: r

I am trying to find a way to do 2 things.

1. Take a dataset and separate it into individual datasets based on its value in a specific variable.
2. Run each of those datasets through a function using a for() or other statement.

This is a very simple version of what I want I am doing now.

```
x <- c("Red", "Red", "Red", "Orange", "Blue", "Orange", "Red", "Blue")
y <- c(2,3,1,4,2,6,4,3)
z <- df(x,y) 

Red <- z[z$x == "Red",]
Blue <- z[z$x == "Blue",]
Orange <- z[z$x == "Orange",]

Function1 <- function(x){
  a <- mean(x$y)
  return(a)}

Mean1 <- Function1(Red)
Mean2 <- Function1(Blue)
Mean3 <- Function1(Orange)

Table <- rbind(Mean1, Mean2)
Table <- rbind(Table, Mean3)

Table
```

I would like to simplify this to automatically create a dataset for each unique 'color', and then run each 'color' dataset through a function.

Appreciate any feedback, thanks!

Comment: Try running your code before posting please. The first line will throw an error. (Fyi, I'm voting to put your question "on hold" until it's edited to be more answerable.)

Comment: You should use lists. See my answer at [How to make a list of data frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) for examples. (I'd even recommend closing this as a dupe.) But essentially you do `df_list = split(z, z$x); mean_list = lapply(df_list, Function1); Table = do.call(rbind, mean_list)`. This is very general. In many cases you don't even need lists and can easily use `dplyr` or `data.table` to do things "by group" on your entire dataframe.

Comment: @Frank my apologies, the "'s got dropped when I copied/pasted.

Comment: Thanks Gregor I will try that.

Comment: @Gregor Your comment is a decent answer. Why not submit it as such?

Comment: Thanks for bumping this old question. I think it serves better as a pointer to the List of Data Frames question - everything in my comment is covered there in more detail.